# Avoid line break in section

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I do have a section name with a pretty long name but which could "nicely" fit on one line. I was wondering, therefore, how I could avoid the line to break, perhaps using some *space compression* and/or *line overflow*.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{Convolutional artificial neural networks --- ConvNets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically, I'd like to have a one-line title (I don't like how it looks like, and gaining an extra line would be also quite helpful).

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example so that one can better assist you.

Comment: Done. I thought my question was clear also without a working example (I'm *just* asking how to squeeze a multi line on one line).

Comment: That title doesn't fit on one line, so the only solution is to shorten it or use a smaller font. The `memoir` class has facilities for doing the latter: see `\setsecheadstyle` and similar macros.

Comment: Could you explain where would you put `\setsecheadstyle`, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want this you could just stick the title in an `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{\mbox{Convolutional artificial neural networks --- ConvNets}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This did the overflow thing. Do you suggest also some space compression, or it would look bad?

Comment: @Atcold It would probably look even worse than `\mbox`, I think. For that matter, the only way of doing that that I can think of just now would be to use `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package to squeeze the text. There may of course be better ways.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the ``\mbox`` trick. This elegantly solves  the issue provided the resulting title is marginally outside the text-area.